# how to implement the class `MyTupleReducer`in flink official document

Tags: apache-flink

I'm learning  [flink document-dataset api](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html)

there's a class called`mytupleReducer`

I'm trying to complete it:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3CjphGQrXP/

but it' full of red line in Intellij.

could you give me a right style of above code?

Thanks for your help~!

PS:

I'm writing part of MyTupleReduce
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/m4rjs6t8QP/

but the return part is Wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that importing the `Reduce` from akka has thrown you off course. Flink's `ReduceFunction<T>` interface needs you to implement a `reduce` method with this signature:

```
T reduce(T value1, T value2) throws Exception;
```

This is a classic reduce that takes two objects of type T and produces a third object of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I have no knowledge about akka now.....

Comment: The pastebin link you shared has `import akka.stream.impl.fusing.Reduce;` in it, and then below you are trying to implement this interface rather than the one from Flink.

Comment: Is there a simple example for it ?I can not find the details in Google,Thanks

Comment: The reduce in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#reduce-on-dataset-grouped-by-keyselector-function is doing the same thing, just for a POJO rather than a Tuple.

Comment: I'm writing part of MyTupleReduce  in https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/m4rjs6t8QP/

but the return part is Wrong. could you help me have a look? Thanks again~

Comment: In that example, the first two fields are both used for grouping. So the return value should be `(in1.f0,in1.f1,in1.f2+in2.f2)`.

Comment: but intellij tell me that it can not resolve this sentence,could you tell me where am I wrong?